# Sum of elements in the power of a matrix

Tags: algorithm, performance, math

Given a matrix `A`, what is the most effective method by which one can obtain the sum of elements of `A^n`?
I was thinking of some property related to matrices that would solve this problem without carrying out `n` multiplications to find `A^n`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP seeks a mathematic approach, nowhere near SO's topic range, post here please: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get n-th power of matrix, you need log(n) matrix multiplications using [exponentiation by squaring approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

P.S. I doubt that formula or property for sum of elements in the power of a matrix could exist - mathematicians discuss just [estimation for specific kinds of matrices](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1103036499)